# Many-to-many relation query with few group options

Tags: sql, many-to-many, relation

My many-to-many relation table has few groups of options and I want to create SQL-query to get product id, which contain at least one option in every group.

```
+------------+-----------+
| product_id | option_id |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          | 1         |
| 1          | 3         |
| 2          | 2         |
| 3          | 4         |
+------------+-----------+
```

I have tried something like that:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM options_to_products
WHERE (option_id = 1 OR option_id = 2)
AND (option_id = 3 OR option_id = 4)
```

It gives nothing, but I suppose to see `1`. Any ideas how to make query like that?

Comment: Edit the question add your desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM options_to_products
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN option_id IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN option_id IN (3, 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

We can also try doing a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT otp1.product_id
FROM options_to_products otp1
INNER JOIN options_to_products otp2
    ON otp1.product_id = otp2.product_id AND
       (otp1.option_id IN (1, 2) AND otp2.option_id IN (3, 4) OR
       otp1.option_id IN (3, 4) AND otp2.option_id IN (1, 2));
```

Comment: Conditional aggregation looks perfect. Thank you!